# c# extend properties to class from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2022

i have two projects , one of projects is added as a reference to another one to use some functions and classes..

how i can extned the origenal class with some new properties/fields that exists in primary project and use it second project ?

if it's in same project i can extend it like

```
public class ClassA : ClassB
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Phone{ get; set; }

}

public class ClassB 
{
    public int id{ get; set; }
    public string someField{ get; set; }

}
```

i need to use the fields in ClassB in project 2 only, and add some values to the object

```
List<ProjectA.ClassA> data = await SomeFunction();
data.ForEach(x =>
{
    x.id= 1;
    x.someField = "some value";
});
```

i have many classes in the primary project and i want to extend all of them with new class in the second project

Comment: what is "the original class" and how does it relate to porject 1 and 2? It's pretty hard to understand this pseudo-code. Please elaborate on what you want to achieve and where exactly you're stuck. Also consider to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: _"if it's in same project i can extend it like"_ - by "extending" you mean inheritance (i.e. `public class ClassB : ClassA`)? If yes - you can do this across projects

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain i'v updated the question with sample

Comment: The second code snip uses ClassA with ClassB fields. That won't work.

Comment: you need to cast every item within your list to `ClassB`. What's your problem?

Comment: it's was my fault typeo with the first code, it's need to be ClassA : ClassB

Answer (score 0):

`SomeFunction` returns a list of objects of type `ClassB`, correct? If you want to access properties of type `ClassB`, your list must be of type `ClassB`. I would not recommend a type cast as it might fail when the returned objects are not of the correct type.

If you only iterate over the data, you could use an `IEnumerable`, which is the interface that all collections implement.

```
IEnumerable<ClassB> data = await SomeFunction();
data.ForEach(x =>
{
    x.id= 1;
    x.someField = "some value";
});
```

If `SomeFunction` only returns objects of type `ClassA`, your code will never work.

C# is a statically typed language. It is generally not possible to dynamically add new properties at runtime unless you work with dynamic objects (look for type ExpandoObject).

Comment: i need to return ClassA the additional properties from ClassB.. i fixed my code in questuin

Comment: @NajiMakhoul I edited my answer, but I don't think that what you want is possible. It is possible to cast an object of type B to it's base type A, but not vice-versa.

Comment: Looks as if the user needs a base type that implements a shared interface and derived types that implement inherited interfaces. Then you can pass something such as IClassB (derived from IClassA) to something that expects an IClassA. Later on you can use it 'as IClassB' and get access to the extension fields. Still requires testing for the interface of that the object implements.